# jQuery non-global module type definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm using webpack and TypeScript in the build step of my project and in the code I'm importing jQuery as a module, meaning it is not defined as a global `$` or `jQuery` variables.
However, the popular [jQuery definition file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) for TypeScript defines the `JQuery` namespace as a global, meaning that the TypeScript compiler doesn't produce an error even when using the jQuery without an `import` or `require` statement – an obviously incorrect behavior in this scenario.

What is the correct way to fix this?

It's worth mentioning that I'm using a `/// <reference path="path/to/jquery.d.ts" />` statement to import the jQuery definition file.